# Modifying a UICollectionViewFlowLayout to change cells positions

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I need to slightly change the way `FlowLayout` draws cells.

I need to set the collection to scroll horizontally and I want to draw cells from left to right, moving to the next line when the width is completely filled and taking into account pagination.

Here some images to clarify my question:

This is the **current behaviour** of the `FlowLayout`:

[image]

this is what I'd like to obtain:

[image]

**Some notes:**

- I need `paginationEnabled = YES`
- I want to fix the rows to a maximum of 2
- I have a fixed number of cells too.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour working with a `UICollectionFlowLayout`? Or is this the case to create a totally custom `UICollectionLayout`?

Comment: I've decided to create a totally custom layout. By the way I let the Question open waiting for your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to manually fill the cells checking the indexpath.row and also checking the width of each cell and self.view.frame.size.width

Comment: So are you suggesting to go for a totally custom layout or just subclassing `UICollectionFlowLayout`?

Comment: I think it would be better to subclass the UICollectionFlowLayout

Comment: Could you provide some more info to your answer? How would you perform subclassing... which methods would you override and how? Provide some contents that help me so that I can consider your answer useful (sorry if it sounds rude).